# PyCord - Leaderboard system, no errors, no response

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord

I am trying to setup a leaderboard system for a discord bot I am making using PyCord. However, it seems like I cannot get this working, perhaps because the "Show 10" part. I get no errors in console and no response, it would be great if someone helps me.

Code:

```
@bot.command(description="Shows you the leaderboard of the whole server.")
async def leaderboard(ctx, type: discord.Option(str)):
    nextButton = discord.ui.Button(label="Next", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    previousButton = discord.ui.Button(label="Previous", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    view = discord.ui.View(timeout=None)
    view.add_item(nextButton)
    view.add_item(previousButton)
    

    if type=="Total":
        cursor = statsdb.execute("SELECT * FROM stat ORDER BY total DESC")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        if result:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboard", color=discord.Color.green())
            for i in range(10):
                embed.add_field(name=f"{i+1}. {result[i][0]}", value=f"Total Questions Answered: {result[i][2]}", inline=False)
            await ctx.respond(embed=embed, view=view)
        async def nextButton_callback(interaction):
            nextPage = stats.db.execute("SELECT * FROM stat ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10")
            result = nextPage.fetchall()
            if result:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboard", color=discord.Color.green())
                for i in range(10):
                    embed.add_field(name=f"{i+1}. {result[i][0]}", value=f"Total Questions Answered: {result[i][2]}", inline=False)
                    if i+1 == len(result):
                        for j in range(10-i):
                            embed.add_field(name=f"{i+1+j}. None", value=f"Total Questions Answered: None", inline=False)
                
                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
            
        async def previousButton_callback(interaction):
            previousPage = stats.db.execute("SELECT * FROM stat ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0")
            result = previousPage.fetchall()
            if result:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboard", color=discord.Color.green())
                for i in range(10):
                    embed.add_field(name=f"{i+1}. {result[i][0]}", value=f"Total Questions Answered: {result[i][2]}", inline=False)
                    if i+1 == len(result):
                        for j in range(10-i):
                            embed.add_field(name=f"{i+1+j}. None", value=f"Total Questions Answered: None", inline=False)

                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)

        
        view.add_item(nextButton_callback)
        view.add_item(previousButton_callback)

    
    if type=="Wins":
        cursor = statsdb.execute("SELECT * FROM stat ORDER BY wins DESC")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        if result:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboard", color=discord.Color.green())
            for i in range(10):
                embed.add_field(name=f"{i+1}. {result[i][0]}", value=f"Wins: {result[i][1]}", inline=False)
            await ctx.respond(embed=embed, view=view)
        async def nextButton_callback(interaction):
            nextPage = stats.db.execute("SELECT * FROM stat ORDER BY wins DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10")
            result = nextPage.fetchall()
            if result:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboard", color=discord.Color.green())
                for i in range(10):
                    embed.add_field(name=f"{i+1}. {result[i][0]}", value=f"Wins: {result[i][1]}", inline=False)
                
                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
            
        async def previousButton_callback(interaction):
            previousPage = stats.db.execute("SELECT * FROM stat ORDER BY wins DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0")
            result = previousPage.fetchall()
            if result:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboard", color=discord.Color.green())
                for i in range(10):
                    embed.add_field(name=f"{i+1}. {result[i][0]}", value=f"Wins: {result[i][1]}", inline=False)
                
                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)

        view.add_item(nextButton_callback)
        view.add_item(previousButton_callback)
```

I tried to use GPT-4, I excepted to it fix it but it just ended up making it worse, so I reverted it.
I tried to ask it to a discord server, I excepted to get correct answers which can help me, but I got nothing proper.

Comment: Are you sure `result` isn't empty? I copied your code, replacing the SQL queries with dummy data, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a few possible issues with your code:

- Typo on line 11 (`statsdb`)

  - (`stats.db` appears on lines 19, 32, 58, and 68)
- Fixed `OFFSET` on lines 19, 32, 58, and 68

  - (If you're intending to [paginate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) the data, then the offset should be set to the first row number you want to return.)

I implemented my solution to this using this database setup:

```py
# Empty class used to define stats
class Thing:
    pass


stats = Thing()

# Create a database connection with some test data
stats.db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = stats.db.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE stat (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, total INTEGER, wins INTEGER);")
for i in range(25):
    cur.execute(
        "INSERT INTO stat (id, total, wins) VALUES (?,?,?);",
        (i, random.randint(0, 100), random.randint(0, 100)),
    )
```

I used a lot of my working knowledge of Python and Pycord to help clean up this code and make it more readable and less redundant. I also added comments everywhere so you can maybe glean some new knowledge from it!

```py
# Options for types of leaderboards, with some attached data that'll help us later
class LeaderboardType(Enum):
    total = {"label": "Total Questions Answered", "column_index": 1}
    wins = {"label": "Wins", "column_index": 2}


items_per_page = 10


# Pycord provides a built-in paginator. Let's use that instead.
class LeaderboardPager(Paginator):
    lb_type: LeaderboardType

    def __init__(self, lb_type: LeaderboardType):
        self.lb_type = lb_type

        # Query the database to find how many rows we have
        row_count = stats.db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stat;").fetchall()[0][0]

        # Create some empty pages so the paginator knows how many pages there are
        super().__init__(["" for _ in range(0, row_count, items_per_page)])

    def get_page_content(self, page):
        offset = self.current_page * items_per_page
        cursor = stats.db.execute(
            # Normally, using string interpolation in SQL queries is a **BIG**
            # no-no. (see https://xkcd.com/327/ for an example of why) If you
            # are including user input as part of a query, you should use a ? in
            # the place where the input should go, then pass the input in as a
            # query parameter.
            # I'm only using string interpolation here because column names cannot
            # be input as parameters, and the possible values are very tightly
            # constrained by the LeaderboardType Enum.
            f"SELECT * FROM stat ORDER BY {self.lb_type.name} DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET CAST(? AS int)",
            (str(offset),) # Don't remove that last comma! Without it, the params won't be considered a tuple!
        )

        # := (aka named assignment, or the walrus operator) is a handy shortcut to assign a
        # variable, and execute the indented block if the value is truthy
        if result := cursor.fetchall():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboard", color=discord.Color.green())
            for i, row in enumerate(result):
                embed.add_field(
                    name=f"{offset+i+1}. {row[0]}",
                    value=f"{self.lb_type.value['label']}: {row[self.lb_type.value['column_index']]}",
                )
            return super().get_page_content(embed)


@bot.command(description="Shows you the leaderboard of the whole server.")
async def leaderboard(
    ctx: discord.ApplicationContext,
    lb_type: discord.Option(
        str, name="type", choices=[v.name for v in list(LeaderboardType)]
    ),
):  # Try not to overwrite built-in function names!
    lb_type = LeaderboardType[lb_type]
    pager = LeaderboardPager(lb_type)
    await pager.respond(ctx.interaction)
```